# Sys.getsizeof returning a constant value on IronPython

Tags: python, ironpython

I'm trying to use sys.getsizeof to determine size of my object 
and I tried the method in command line, but the method returns 8 no matter what the input is

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof([])
8
>>> sys.getsizeof([1,2,3,4])
8
>>> sys.getsizeof('')
8
>>> sys.getsizeof([0 for x in range(10**7)])
8
```

why am I getting this, did I do anything wrong ?
I'm using ironpython 2.7, will that be any difference ?

Comment: With python3.7 this gives in order: 64, 96, 49, 81528056

Comment: `getsizeof()` is implementation-defined; it's not guaranteed to be meaningful. And yes, as a thing that's implementation-defined, it can be expected to be different between implementations (f/e, CPython vs IronPython). A reasonable guess is that the constant `8` is pointer size on your platform.